# Representing the Footer in the Dashboard

Tags: website-design, gui-design, dashboard, footers

I want to design a dashboard and I have a great deal of elements in my homepage footer such as:

- List item
- Contact us
- About us
- Some services
- Pricing
- Social media
- Copyright
- ...

Is removing the footer good practice or not? If not, how should I represent them in the dashboard? Is it necessary to make available all of them in the dashboard?

Comment: Not intended as any sort of formal answer, more as an aside, but in my experience the only webpage footers I've ever thought could have stood to have been cut from a page are the footers on pages that invoke endless-scrolling making it virtually impossible to even reach the footer. Any and every other time there's a footer on the page, I've at least appreciated that a website has made the effort to format content by some sense of a conventional paradigm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### REMOVAL OF THE FOOTER IS NOT A GOOD PRACTICE

1. The footer is a useful place where one can locate content like navigational links, copyright info, external links, social media links and more.
2. The footer is usually injected onto every page of your website from a central location. This is very useful for many reasons including not having to update every page when you change something in this area.
3. In design psychology, there is a something called the "[Mere-exposure effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mere-exposure_effect)" Which is very effective at driving sales and reducing the [bounce rate](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009409?hl=en).

> ### [Why is it That Many Websites Features Look so Similar?](https://baileystreetdesign.com/2016/10/21/web-design-and-the-mere-exposure-effect/)
>
> One of the psychological factors at work is the ‘mere exposure
>   effect’: We seek information to confirm our beliefs. If you are used
>   to going on a website and the menu is horizontal across the top of the
>   page. That the home page is on the left and the contact page on the
>   right. That an underlined word is a link you may be under the
>   influence of what is called “confirmation bias”. This exposure effect
>   reveals a preference that most people have for the familiar.
>
> Most business owners want a website because they have ‘content’ that
>   they believe is useful to their customers. It is reasonable then that
>   you want your customers to be able to find information and data to be
>   able to make a decision. That decision may be to make an appointment,
>   buy something, or provide personal information. It is an unpleasant
>   and frustrating experience when you visit a website, and you are not
>   able to find what you want.
>
> In a website, design familiarity plays a primary role in aesthetic
>   appeal and acceptance. Something is reassuring about the “exposure
>   effect”. People like things more when they are repeatedly exposed to
>   them. People like their websites when they have some confidence that
>   if they click on an underlined word that it will link to another web
>   page or website. Contrary to what cynics would say, familiarity tends
>   to breed liking, not contempt.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, footer is useful, because:

- Increases credibility
- Is a site map
- Quickly navigates

The possibilities:

- Trim parts with a lower priority (in the future, the analyst will define the lower click-through rate of the links)
- Not display all elements at once, only apply the overlap model